# MySQL Query Optimization?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, optimization

So I have a `DB` with *~5 million rows* and I am trying to optimize the load times. My DB has columns and indexes as optimized as I can think so I assume its the query. This query runs on a table with *~5 million rows* and returns 40 of them, but it takes 101 seconds.

If I remove the `timezone` conversions the same query takes *0.0015* seconds but returns slightly different results because of the timezone difference. How could I optimize to get the correct results with more speed?

```
SELECT *, date(CONVERT_TZ(eventDate, "US/Eastern", "America/New_York")) as `timezoneDate`
FROM `transactions`
WHERE `isValid` = X
AND `storeID` = X
AND date(CONVERT_TZ(eventDate, "US/Eastern", "America/New_York")) >= '2014-11-19'
AND date(CONVERT_TZ(eventDate, "US/Eastern", "America/New_York")) <= '2014-11-25'
ORDER BY `eventDate`
```

Also if it was not clear before, the second timezone I am converting to changes depending on user, so right now its America/New_York which is the same as *US/Eastern* but it changes.

Comment: you can't. you're using derived values, and that means no indexes. e.g. `where foo=1` is fine and could use any applicable indexes. `where somefunc(foo)=1` isn't, because the result of `somefunc` is unindexed.

Comment: Would it be faster to for example, remove the timezone restrictions, grab the results with + and - one day, then run a PHP loop t o calculate and remove extra results? I figure running a timezone convert on 10-12 extra rows and removing some would be faster than 100 seconds.

Comment: If the number returned is small enough, perhaps run it without the calls to CONVERT_TZ and a slightly wider net (2014-11-18 to 2014-11-26 perhaps), then narrow it after. doh, that occured to you while I was typing, sorry.

Comment: Is the query slow with timezone conversion in only the select as well? How rows are returned in the 0.0015 seconds?

Comment: The results are returned in 0.0015 seconds if I remove all the date stuff and just do eventDate => '2014-11-19' etc. I would remove all three of the timezone converts

Comment: @JRD The one in the SELECT only needs to run on the results that match the criteria, the criteria needs to be run on *all records*.

Comment: What is the performance if you just leave it in the select? Do you still get 0.0015?

Comment: If I leave it in the select I get 0.45, so substantially  better but still way better than 100.

Comment: reverse the logic. do the tz/time conversion on your fixed values , e.g. `eventdate = date(convert_tz('2014-11-19'))`-type thing. then you CAN use indexes. because the indexed field is being used "raw".

Comment: .45 does not seem substantially worse than 101 seconds. You only want to convert the timezone once anyway, instead of 3 times like you have it.

Comment: Sorry typo, I meant better.

Comment: @MarcB You should enter that as answer IMO, as that would be the best approach - to understand the timezone the `eventDate` is stored in and the timezone the user is in and to perform the timezone conversions on the date and time you are using for comparison in your WHERE.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the two timezones are identical according to the standard (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was a mix of JRD, TZHX, and MarcB's comments. I ended up doing a select without the time zone but increasing my selection radius by plus and minus one day. This got my ~5 million rows down to about 50, however since it was slightly more than I wanted I then ran the original query but only on the 50 results returned by the first select. This resulted in all of the exact same data being returned but in only 0.11 seconds. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1):

What about postponing the date filtering:

```
select * from (     
SELECT *, date(CONVERT_TZ(eventDate, "US/Eastern", "America/New_York")) as `timezoneDate`
    FROM `transactions`
    WHERE `isValid` = X
    AND `storeID` = X
)
where timezoneDate between '2014-11-19' and '2014-11-25'
ORDER BY timezoneDate
```

Comment: Won't work as spelled out because `WHERE` requires expressions, not aliases.

Comment: Say what? I don't follow. `select alias from (select 'text' as alias) q where alias = 'text';` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your data, you should be sure that you have an index on `transactions(storeId, isvalid, eventdate)`.

If this doesn't help performance, then your options are more limited.  One is to define a "canonical" event time for New York.  This requires a trigger to do the conversion.

A second option is similar, but it involves keeping the time difference as a separate column.

I would suggest time zone conversions on the constants, but the two time zones should be the same.  I don't know why they would be returning different results.